# How to group a column of string in vb.net report?

Tags: vb.net

Hi i want that merge columns of string values join in single cell in vb report by using group

Data

ID               Name

1               paint

1               cross

1               less

2               to

2               gain

3               increase

I need in report as

ID            Name

1          paint, cross, less

2          to, gain

3          increase

Comment: What cell is this a DataGridView Cell? Also what sort of report. Much more information needed in order to answer this

Comment: rdlc report not datagridview

Comment: i need a report i want to group table in report. if i group ID column means it takes the name as paint only. i need paint,cross,less in same field when i group my ID. these group function can be used in vb rdlc report only